# Create an Array of the Last 30 Days Using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am trying to create an array starting with today and going back the last 30 days with PHP and I am having trouble.  I can estimate but I don’t know a good way of doing it and taking into account the number of days in the previous month etc.  Does anyone have a good solution? I can’t get close but I need to make sure it is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 41):

Try this:

```
<?php    
$d = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) 
    $d[] = date("d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days'));
?>
```

Comment: I think you meant for the date to be assigned to $d[i], not $d[].

Comment: For those that don't know, what `$d[]` does here is add result to the end of the array.

Comment: for really new people, it may be nice to note that the output of `$d` in the answer is only the day and to include the month and year you can do this: `"d-m-y"`. Please review php's `date()` function for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Here is advance latest snippet for the same,

```
$today     = new DateTime(); // today
$begin     = $today->sub(new DateInterval('P30D')); //created 30 days interval back
$end       = new DateTime();
$end       = $end->modify('+1 day'); // interval generates upto last day
$interval  = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1d interval range
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end); // it always runs forwards in date
foreach ($daterange as $date) { // date object
    $d[] = $date->format("Y-m-d"); // your date
}
print_r($d);
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c25cf124a085dd58d074f8a8a48931f87c16717).

Official [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to show sales of the past X days,
[As asked in this closed question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193191/how-to-get-last-7-days-using-php#*=*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193191/how-to-get-last-7-days-using-php#_=_), this worked for me.

```
  $sales = Sale::find_all();//the sales object or array

  for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
    $sale_sum = 0;  //sum of sale initial
    if($i==0){ 
    $day = strtotime("today"); 
  } else {
   $day = strtotime("$i days ago");
  }
  $thisDayInWords = strftime("%A", $day);

  foreach($sales as $sale){
    $date = strtotime($sale->date_of_sale)); //May 30th 2018 10:00:00 AM
    $dateInWords = strftime("%A", $date);

    if($dateInWords == $thisDayInWords){
        $sale_sum += $sale->total_sale;//add only sales of this date... or whatever
    } 
  } 
  //display the results of each day's sale
  echo $thisDayInWords."-".$sale_sum; ?> 

 }
```

Before you get angry:
I placed this answer here to help someone who was directed here from that question. Couldn't answer there :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use time to control the days:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
{
    $timestamp = time();
    $tm = 86400 * $i; // 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400 = 1 day in seconds
    $tm = $timestamp - $tm;

    $the_date = date("m/d/Y", $tm);
}
```

Now, within the for loop you can use the $the_date variable for whatever purposes you might want to. :-)

Comment: Pedrin, watch out for this method using time. I used to do this, then noticed that it won't calculate correctly at certain times involving day-light savings time.
Instead, I would advise using the strtotime function.
-Matt

Comment: you are missing a $ before i++.. thanks for the useful loop :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
    array_unshift($d,strtotime('-'. $i .' days'));
```

Comment: Some explanation about how this solution works and why you think it is a good solution would be an improvement on this post.