# Get all dates from last 30 days (datetime objects)

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get an array of datetime objects but failing miserably.

I want to take today's date, and get all dates within the last 30 days.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$begin = $today->sub(new DateInterval('P30D'));

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 Day
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $today);

$range = [];
foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $range[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

When I dump out `$range`, I get an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4312439/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$begin = $today->sub(new DateInterval('P30D'));
```

to

```
$begin = new DateTime();
$begin->sub(new DateInterval('P30D'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you overwrite `$today` so `$today` and `$begin` is exactly the same

```
$today =  new DateTime();
$copy = clone $today;
$begin = $copy->sub(new DateInterval('P30D'));

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 Day
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $today);

$range = [];
foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $range[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

will work

Comment: Alternatively you can `clone` it. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: yeah i figured out this don't work.. thanks didn't even know clone existed like this in php

Answer (score 1):

the "sub" method modifies the source object, as well as outputting the object itself as the return value (really this is intended for method chaining). It doesn't just create a new object with the new date.

```
$begin = $today->sub(new DateInterval('P30D'));
```

modifies `$today` as well as outputting a copy which you then declare as `$begin`. This results in both objects having the same date, and thus there's no time interval over which to iterate.

See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

You need to create a separate object for your end date:

```
$begin = new DateTime();
$begin->sub(new DateInterval('P30D'));
$end = new DateTime();

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 Day
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$range = [];
foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $range[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
var_dump($range);
```

See it working at https://eval.in/867948

Comment: Please transfer this good answer to this much earlier duplicate that is loaded with not-so-good answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/337760/2943403